# Can Parents Of A Minor Legally Take Away Something That They Own

Tags: family-law, minor, iowa

I'm under the age of 18 (a minor). Do my parents have the right to take away my personal property?

To clarify this I should mention that my parents are divorced and my dad has legal custody of me but kicked me out and I'm now living with his parents. My dad doesn't want me in his house or on his property. Both of my parents have told me "*You're a minor so you don't own anything! Not the money you make or the clothes on your body!"* I have purchased stuff that is important to me with the money I've made from work and is on my dad's property. Do I have a right to go and get my stuff since I do not live under his roof?

If so what is the legal document that shows proof that I can go and retrieve my property?